# Syntax mistakes

Tags: java, android, syntax

I wrote this code to return value from calculator:

```
try {
    startActivity(intent);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // User pressed OK.
            double value = data.getDoubleExtra("X", Double.NaN);
            if (Double.isNaN(value)) {
                // Calculation result was "Error".
            } else {
                // Calculation result ok.
            }
        } else {
        // User pressed cancel or back button.
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives me syntax mistakes for brackets, commas and word Intent in the line:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

some why it requires semicolon instead of all those signs. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: You're getting the errors because you're trying to define a new method inside another (without declaring something like an anonymous inner class).  You also happen to be missing a `catch` clause, but I can't tell if you just left that off...  Oh, if you're expecting `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` to _modify_ `requestCode`, it's not going to (dunno if that's what you're anticipating).

Comment: Do not edit previous question with new one. In this case answer and questions dont make any resemblance. If you caught into another problem then ask different question.

Comment: You should be more accurate in your questions.  You didn't write this code, you copied and pasted.  If you look at where you got the code, it doesn't work there either for the same reason!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)...
```

declares a method. You can't just declare a method anywhere; it must be in a class body. Here you're trying to declare `onActivityResult` in another method but Java does not allow that.

Comment: it doesn't show a mistake on the method itself, but on brackets and commas. This is just taken from my code

Comment: @L.G. That's because the IDE truly has no idea what you're trying to do, so it just tries to throw the best syntax errors it can. Matt is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing some things. If you're in Eclipse, the editor tries to show you where your syntax error lie, but in cases like this one, there are too many errors for this feature to be useful.

The Java language (like Matt Ball says) takes your lines to be a declaration of a method. What it is expecting at that place is an instruction (which is why it tells you it's expecting a  colon). If you put that in, it will tell you the protected and void keywords are mistaken, and so on and so on...